# What is the environment variable for the All Users Desktop path that works across all versions of Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm trying to write a batch file that can copy a file from my computer to all computers in a list. It needs to be copied to the AllUsers Desktop (I'll use a domain admin account to run the batch file).

On my Win7 system, the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` returns C:\ProgramData. Is there a variable that returns the AllUsers Desktop path across every version of Windows? I have a mix of XP, Vista, and Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no environment variable holding desktop path, but with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2000638/11343) you can see how to get it in batch (answers are for current user desktop, you'll need to adapt them for all users desktop

Answer (score 15):

It is `%public%` in Windows 7...

Comment: Necro: `%public%\Desktop`, to be precise.

Answer (score 3):

%public% works for Windows 10 and Windows 2011 Server and up

%ALLUSERSPROFILE% is used in Windows XP

But, you can look to see what the available variables are by running "SET" from a command prompt

Answer (score 1):

in vista, 7, 8

%userprofile%\..\Default\Desktop