# Find the desktop path in R

Tags: r, path, desktop

In python, one can get the path to the desktop on a Windows computer using:

```
os.sep.join((os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop"))
```

Is there something equivalent in R?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `~` expands to your documents home, rather than your user profile where the desktop is normally located. I recommend you use `Sys.getenv` to find your user profile:

```
file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),"Desktop")
```

Comment: how to get the R style path? this returns "C:\\Users\\Owner/Desktop"

Comment: `file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),"Desktop",fsep="\\")`

Answer (score 11):

Something like (like mentioned in the comment) :

```
file.path(path.expand('~'),'Desktop')
```

Comment: It seems that Windows translates "~" to "/Users/<user_name>/Documents" and NOT "/Users/<user_name>".

Comment: this worked for me: `file.path(dirname(path.expand('~')),'Desktop')`. James answer only works if your User folder is at the standard location

Answer (score 2):

Can't add a comment to James' answer, so here's another Answer.

On a terminal server network:

`file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),"Desktop")` gives me the wrong result

`file.path(Sys.getenv("HOMESHARE"),"Desktop")` gives me the right result

On my local machine it's the other way round. I haven't yet found a solution which works in both environments.

EDITED TO ADD

OK, this is a bit of a kludge based on the link I gave in my comment. A Windows expert could probably do it better, but I think this works in both environments and should be robust against changes in Desktop path.

Create a VBscript file to return the Desktop path: getDesk.vbs

```
dim WSHShell, desktop, pathstring, objFSO
set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WSHshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
desktop = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
pathstring = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(desktop)
WScript.Echo pathstring
```

Now in R you can execute the VBscript to return the Desktop path

```
system("cscript //nologo getDesk.vbs", intern=TRUE)
```

Comment: From this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000638/whats-the-environment-variable-for-the-path-to-the-desktop?rq=1 it looks as if any approach based simply on environment variables may not be very portable.